# Can't connect to remote mysql database using SSL and SHA256 password authentication

Tags: mysql, php, ssl

I can successfully connect over a secure connection from the web server's cli but get an error message when testing connection through php script.

**mysql status from the web server cli**

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      9
Current database:   
Current user:       test@db.test.com
SSL:            Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     0.0.0.0 via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         3 days 4 hours 53 min 35 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 17  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 107  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 26  Queries per second avg: 0.000
```

**SSL variables from web server cli**

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| have_openssl  | YES             |
| have_ssl      | YES             |
| ssl_ca        | ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                 |
| ssl_cert      | server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                 |
| ssl_crl       |                 |
| ssl_crlpath   |                 |
| ssl_key       | server-key.pem  |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

**Grants from web server cli**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test@0.0.0.0                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'0.0.0.0'              |
| GRANT SELECT ON `testDB`.* TO 'test'@'0.0.0.0' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Character set using utf8mb4 from web server cli**

```
+--------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                  |
+--------------------------+------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                 |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                |
| character_set_system     | utf8                   |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

**User permissions on remote database**

```
+------------------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
| user             | host        | plugin                | ssl_type |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
| test             | 0.0.0.0     | sha256_password       | X509     |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
```

**Certificate permissions on web server**

```
apache@web:~$ ls -al /etc/mysql-client
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 24 02:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 99 root root 4096 Mar 30 20:04 ..
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root root 1107 Mar 24 02:30 ca.pem
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root root 1107 Mar 24 02:30 client-cert.pem
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root root 1679 Mar 24 02:30 client-key.pem
```

**PHP Test Script on web server**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=db.test.com;port=3306;dbname=testDB;charset=utf8mb4';
$dbuser = 'test';
$dbpass = 'sha256-hash';

$dboptions = array (
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql-client/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   =>'/etc/mysql-client/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     =>'/etc/mysql-client/ca.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false 
);

    try {
        $conn = new PDO($dsn,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dboptions);
        if($conn){
                echo "Connection established";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Successful network connection from web server to database server**

```
Connection to 0.0.0.0 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

**Error Message from web server**

```
apache@web:~$ php -f test.php
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
```

The few questions I have are:

- Should the database password used in the php script be set to the plain-text password string or the sha256 hash?  I have tried both and neither work.
- Since the certificates are in /etc with global permissions and the php script has explicit file paths, is creating a database user account on the web server necessary?  For example, my "test" user on the web server is only really used to test the mysql connection from command line.  I don't see how apache is dependent on the test user.
- Any php.ini settings I should take a look at?  The only one I have tested was changing "open_basedir" to include the /etc/mysql-client directory but that didn't do anything either.
- Does anybody know if [Bug #77595](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77595) has been fixed?
- Has anyone actually gotten sha256_password authentication over SSL using PHP to actually work?

### **UPDATE #1**

Supposedly [Bug #77595](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77595) has been fixed in php7.2.3 so I fired up a new VM with ubuntu18.04 which has php7.2.3 as the default package, still no luck.  The only error string that seemed useful from var_dump was

```
"PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error 
messages: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"
```

mysql login from command line still works with the same certificates it is just php doesn't like them.  I scp'd them from the mysql server so the chance of formatting error is unlikely.

Comment: Have you run `var_dump($e)` in your catch block? Commonly there is additional information available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a clear answer for this problem.  My assumption is that something is going on with yaSSL.  I ended up using Percona instead which implements openSSL.